# Why does Jetty standalone JAR download itself? (packaged with Maven)

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a java project where I'm using embedded jetty, and I also need to package this into a stand-alone JAR. I have succeeded in doing all of this and gotten a servlet (HelloServlet) to respond correctly and everything. The problem is that if I go to the root (localhost:8080 in this case) I get a file download. When I inspected it I noticed it got the same size as my JAR, so I renamed it to .zip and opened it, lo and behold, it was my stand-alone JAR.

Why is this happening?

How can I prevent this? (am I doing something wrong/funky?)

Comments on structure are welcome, and if something's not clear I'll happily provide more information.

/src/main/java/my/package/MyServer.java

```
package my.package;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class MyServer
{
   private Server server;

   private MyServer() {}

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      BasicConfigurator.configure();
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyServer");

      int port = 8080;

      Server server = new Server(port);

      logger.info("Server created at port " + port);

      ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = MyServer.class.getProtectionDomain();

      logger.info(protectionDomain);

      URL url = protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation();

      logger.info(url);

      String rootPath = url.toExternalForm();

      logger.info("rootPath: " + rootPath);

      WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
      webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
      webAppContext.setResourceBase(rootPath);
      webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
      webAppContext.setWar(rootPath);

      webAppContext.addServlet(HelloServlet.class, "/hello");

      server.setHandler(webAppContext);

      try
      {
         server.start();
         server.join();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(100);
      }

   }
}
```

/src/main/java/my/package/HelloServlet.java

```
package my.package;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello Servlet!!!</h1>");
      response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());
   }
}
```

/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.package</groupId>
  <artifactId>myserver</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My Server</name>
  <url>http://www.fake.nogo</url>

  <properties>
    <jettyVersion>9.2.13.v20150730</jettyVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.13.v20150730</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>myserver</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.6.v20141205</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>my.package.MyServer</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

/src/main/assembly/distribution.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>standalone</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory></baseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>My Server</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

I do `mvn clean package` and then `java -jar target/myserver-standalone.jar` to run it.

Comment: What is logged as your rootPath? If you start your application from a jar, it should be a file: url pointing to the jar, not the folder containing the jar. I guess using this URL as resource base should be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @MichaelKoch Thank you for your response! The logged rootPath actually points to the stand-alone jar (otherwise I guess the HelloServlet wouldn't work?)

Comment: I managed to get it to work, by scrapping everything and building from this -> https://github.com/thomasWeise/standAloneJSPsWithJetty

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the maven-assembly-plugin this way:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <finalName>myserver-standalone</finalName>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>my.package.MyServer</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I tried your solution, with the addition of the executions-tag from my starting solution (otherwise it won't build the final stand-alone jar.) It works just the same as my starting solution, though.